# Is there a decidable problem that we know for sure cannot be solved in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

If yes, could you say an example?
P=NP would result in NP problems being solvable in polynomial time, but there would still be problems in the EXPTIME class.

Comment: Please incorporate the question in the body, show us your research, and format your question properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known that P $\ne$ EXPTIME.  Therefore, any [EXPTIME-complete problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME#EXPTIME-complete) suffices.  For instance: given a deterministic Turing machine $M$, an input $x$, and a positive integer $k$ (represented in binary), determine whether $M$ halts on input $x$ within at most $k$ steps.

Related: [How do we know for sure that EXPTIME ≠ P?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/58116/755), [Halting problem in EXP-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/112684/755).

Answer (score 0):

Given an integer n > 0, let x = A(n) be the value of the big Ackerman function. Is the sum of decimal digits of x greater then $4.5 \cdot \log_{10}(x)$?