Is it known whether EXP is contained/not-contained in P/log?
Checking the complexity zoo (https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:P), I can only read that "if NP is contained in P/log then P = NP", so, right now, there must be no proof for EXP contained in P/log, but maybe it is proven that EXP is not contained in P/log somewhere. Can someone clarify me whether this is the case, please?
Any clarification or further reading suggestion will be really appreciated.

Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/58116/755

EXP is not contained in P/log. This can be likely proved by direct diagonalization, extending the proof of $\let\R\mathsf\R{P\ne EXP}$ as in the time-hierarchy theorem, using the fact that there are only polynomially many advices of length $O(\log n)$ for any given $n$. However, it also follows easily from the result you quote from the Complexity Zoo, so I will present this proof:
Assume for contradiction that $\R{EXP\subseteq P/log}$. Then, in particular, $\R{NP\subseteq P/log}$, hence $\R{P = NP}$, hence all levels $\Sigma^\mathrm P_k$ of the polynomial-time hierarchy collapse to P. Then all levels of the exponential-time hierarchy collapse to EXP as well, as $\Sigma^\R{EXP}_k\subseteq\R{EXP}^{\Sigma^\R P_k}=\R{EXP^P=EXP}$. However, this contradicts the assumption $\R{EXP\subseteq P/log\subseteq P/poly}$, because there exist languages in the exponential-time hierarchy (in fact, in MA-EXP${}\subseteq\Sigma^\R{EXP}_2$) that require superpolynomial-size circuits.
[An alternative ending: $\R{EXP\subseteq P/poly}$ implies $\R{EXP=\Sigma^P_2}$ by a result of Meyer (improved to $\R{EXP=MA}$ by Babai, Fortnow & Lund). Together with $\R{P=\Sigma^P_2}$, this gives $\R{EXP=P}$, contradicting the time-hierarchy theorem.]
